# How to get API URL using chrome/fiddler dev tool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, google-chrome-devtools, fiddler

I have a get API call from my asp.net mvc controller using HTTP client. API returns json data and also my controller returns json data. In network tab in chrome dev tool I can get the details of my controller call and the data but I am not getting any information about that API call.

Is it possible to inspect/ track API call details using chrome or fiddler? If yes how? Or is there any other tool that will intercept those call also.

Comment: Are you doing the calls client side (ajax)?

Comment: Yes I am calling my controller using Ajax. And webapi from controller using HTTP client

Answer (score 1):

The network tab in Chrome tracks all traffic to and from the client.

You will see all of the calls sent from the server to the browser.  This includes images, css, javascript, etc.  However, it also shows the result of ajax calls.

For an example, go to [This page](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first) and open Chrome Developer Tools. Then go to the network tab.  Then simply click on the demo button and you will see the call pop up.

[image]